# How to print multiple letters in a string when combining two prompts

Tags: python

I am trying to write a code that creates usernames from the users first and last name but I'm not sure how to have multiple letters printed from a string (or if that's the correct method that I should be using)

I was hoping for the output to look something like:
"Enter first name: Georgie
Enter last name: Walsh
Your username is: GWals"

I already have the prompts for the Entering first and last name I just didn't know how to get the GWals part.
I was thinking put {first_name[0]} to print it out but I didn't know how to get the 4 letters of the last name.

Edit: if the last name is less than 4 characters then I would like it to print an asterix at the end e.g. Peter Pan would print PPan*

Comment: Just use string concatenation with `+`.

Comment: Slicing: `last_name[:4]` gets the first 4 characters.

Comment: What happens if a user has a surname of less that 4 chars?